# How to use jQuery to select all text inside paragraph after specific character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use jQuery to find specific character, in this case "#" inside one or more paragraphs, remove that character, and wrap everything after in span tag.

Here is HTML example:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet # consectetur adipiscing elit<p>
```

And jQuery should convert code above into this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <span>consectetur adipiscing elit</span></p>
```

I spent few hours on this already and I know solution should be relatively simple, but I can't find it. Is there any jQuery guru willing to help? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a ***[working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WLYWy/)***:

**HTML:**

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet # consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("p:contains('#')").each(function() {

   var $this = $(this),
       splitText = $this.text().split("#"),
       formattedText = splitText[0] + "<span>" + splitText[1] + "</span>";

   $this.html(formattedText);

});
```

**-- In case you wanted to keep nesting spans for multiple occurrences: --**

Use this ***[working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMaverick/6WAVN/)***:

**HTML:**

```
<p>Lorem ip#sum dolor sit amet # consectetur adip#iscing elit</p>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("p:contains('#')").each(function() {

   var $this = $(this),
       thisText = $this.text(),
       numberOfOccurrences = thisText.split("#").length,
       formattedText = thisText.replace(/\#/g, "<span>");

    for (var i = 1; i < numberOfOccurrences; i++) { formattedText += "</span>"; }

    $this.html(formattedText);

});
```

**Update Notes:**

- *Multiple Occurrence jsFiddle was updated to remove the extra var splitText, as it was unnecessary.*
- *Multiple Occurrence jsFiddle was moved and css was updated to visually show the spans.*

Comment: Do note though, that if you have more than one # in a paragraph, you will need to write more code that will handle that scenario.  I didn't know how exactly what you wanted to handle that scenario, so I just left it like you asked for originally.

Comment: Thanks, at this moment I believe I will have only one, but feel free to update your code if you think solution with multiple # would not take too much of your time.

Comment: Edited the answer for multiple occurrences, based on the assumption that you would want to keep nesting span tags.

Comment: You rock! Just wondering, is it necessary to declare $(this) as variable at begging. Why not just using $(this) in the code? This saves one line of code I guess.

Comment: It's called Caching. Every time you use $(this) it's querying the DOM.  Why not just assign it to a temporary variable and keep re-using that variable, thereby only querying the DOM once?

Comment: ... and that's why I'm begginer :) Thanks Scott! Time for me to go home now.

Comment: No problem!  We are all always learning, no matter the expertise. =D

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
$("p:contains('#')").each(function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   var thisText = $(this).text().split("#");
   $this.html(thisText[0] + "<span>" + thisText[1] + "</span>";
});
```

Comment: Hi John, I tested your code and works fine, thanks. There is only small glitch. I'm having those span tags displayed as text because browser would render them like this:`<p>Test &lt;span&gt; 01&lt;/span&gt;</p>
<p>Test &lt;span&gt; 02&lt;/span&gt;</p>
<p>Test &lt;span&gt; 03&lt;/span&gt;</p>
<p>Test &lt;span&gt; 04&lt;/span&gt;</p>`
Is there solution for this?
BTW, there is missing parentheses after closing span tag and I can't edit your code since there is 6 character minimum edit.

Comment: @user715782 - Change $this.text -> $this.html

Comment: @Klikero   yes sorry I have edited my answer for you.  you should use $this.html instead

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$("p").each(function(){
var text = $(this).text().split("|"); 
$(this).html(""); 
var final = text[0] + "<span>" + text[1] + "</span>"; $(this).html(final);
});
```

Comment: Hi Naveed, I tested your solution but looks like there are some bugs. This is what I got from the page with 4 test paragraphs. Note that every paragraph has unique number. 

`<p>Test <span> 01Test </span></p>
<p>Test <span> 01Test </span></p>
<p>Test <span> 01Test </span></p>
<p>Test <span> 01Test </span></p>`

Comment: Sure, this is html:
 `<p>Test | 01</p>
<p>Test | 02</p>
<p>Test | 03</p>
<p>Test | 04</p>`
And this is jQuery:
`$(function() {

 var text = $("p").text().split("|");
 $("p").html("");
 var final = text[0] + "<span>" + text[1] + "</span>";
 $("p").html(final);

});`

Comment: Updated the code. Take a look at the demo also: http://jsfiddle.net/naveed_ahmad/Zsbny/

Comment: Thanks for update Naveed. This works great too! Sorry I can't vote-up your solution since I still don't have reputation 15 :), this is my first post.

Comment: That's not a problem as far as I could help you some way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[**Here's an example of the following →**](http://jsfiddle.net/gVY3g/)

```
$('p').each(function(i,elem){
    var $this = $(this),
        tStr = $this.text(),
        res = tStr.replace(/(^.*)(\#.*$)/, '$1<span>$2</span>').replace('#','');

    $this.html(res);
});
```

Comment: Although this was not requirement, I would like everyone to note that this was only solution that didn't remove content after # tag if there was more than one # per paragraph. It would show # tag and content after instead which I believe is a plus. Thanks again mVChr.

Comment: I do like this route, however I would point out though, that it didn't handle the multiple #'s correctly.  It only removes the first # occurrence and then only wraps the last # occurrence with the span tags.